# How to know the type of the event when using cloud function 2nd gen?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to migrate to Could Functions 2nd gen. Here is what I have tried:

```
import {
  onDocumentWritten,
  Change,
  FirestoreEvent
} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

exports.myfunction = onDocumentWritten("users/{userId}", (event) => {
  console.log(event.data.after.data());
});
```

I following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen) but there is nothing mentioned about how to know what kind of event happened when using `onDocumentWritten`? Is it created, updated or deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test some part of the event to know the type of event

```
exports.myfunction = onDocumentWritten("users/{userId}", (event) => {
  console.log(event.data.after.data());
    // If the document does not exist, it was deleted
    const document =  event.data.after.data();

    // If the document does not exist, it's a creation
    const previousValues =  event.data.before.data();

    // Else, it's an update.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I thought I can read a flag, or something. But it sounds reasonable, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Usually you use this event when you want to do generic things, whatever the event type. Else, use Updated, Created or Deleted events. Sure, you will create 3 functions, and not 1, but you pay only when the function runs, and it won't be more expensive to use 3 partially used functions, than a single always used function

Comment: As Guillaume covered, unless you are using handling something for all three events, you are better off splitting each action onto their own function. But if you did handle all three, you can build a "change type" flag using `const { before, after } = event.data, changeType = !before.exists() ? "created" : (after.exists() ? "updated" : "deleted");`.

Comment: @samthecodingman You should have true. I'm very bad at NodeJS and some smarter solution could exist!

Answer (score 2):

I had written this code which uses the same concept as samthcodingman, so this is how it would look. As mentioned, for all three events.

Javascript

```
import {
    onDocumentWrite,
    Change,
    FirestoreEvent
} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

exports.myfunction = onDocumentWrite("users/{userId}", (change,context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();

    if (!previousValue) {
        // This is a create operation
        console.log("Document created:", newValue);
    } else if (!newValue) {
        // This is a delete operation
        console.log("Document deleted:", previousValue);
    } else {
        // This is an update operation
        console.log("Document updated:", newValue);
    }
});
```

So, using the change object. If change.before is null, it's a create. if change.after is null, it's a delete. Otherwise, it's an update operation.